# payment of an initial amount

Tags: civicontribute

The CiviCRM codebase and this (fixed) issue https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-11387 seem to suggest CiviCRM supports an interface to configure initial payments.

The database table for events (civicrm_event) has:
'initial_amount_label' => '',
'initial_amount_help_text' => '',
'min_initial_amount' => '',

[image]

My question would be: what is necessary to enable this seemingly hidden (and beautiful) functionality?